# Swift, MyClass, optional (MyClass?), is not convertible to MyClass

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to use generics to have a common method for subclasses of NSManagedObject, but I'm getting an error when Swift seems not to be able to find/convert the generic to the concrete class:

```
/// NSManagedObject+Helper.swift
///
import Foundation

extension NSManagedObject {
    public static func inserta<T>() -> T? {
        let name = self.entityName()
        return CoreDataManager.createRow(inEntityNamed: name) as? T
    }
}
```

```
/// MySwitch+CoreDataClass.swift
///
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(MySwitch)
public class MySwitch: NSManagedObject {

}
```

```
 1 extension MySwitch {
 2 
 3     @NSManaged public var key: String?
 4     @NSManaged public var sValue: String?
 5     @NSManaged public var value: String?
 6     
 7     public class func insert(withKey key: String, value: String, sValue: String? = nil) throws -> MySwitch {
 8         if let row = self.inserta() as? MySwitch {
 9             row.key = key
10             row.value = value
11             if let sValue = sValue {
12                 row.sValue = sValue
13             }
14             return row
15         }
16         throw CoreDataError.create_row
17     }
18 }
```

So call in line 8 gives the error **'MySwitch?' is not convertible to 'MySwitch'**.
By removing the casting, I get the error: **Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred**
By changing line 8 to be `MySwitch.self.inserta() as? MySwitch` it will show the same **'MySwitch?' is not convertible to 'MySwitch'** error.

I think I'm missing telling Swift what the `T` is about because I also get the warning:

```
Cast from '_?' to unrelated type 'MySwitch' always fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue I have with generics. I need to first declare a variable of MySwitch as optional:

```
1 let mySwitch: MySwitch? = inserta()
2 if let row = mySwitch {...
```

That way I'm telling Swift what type `T` is.